# Nativescript Angular Project not running after plugin-filepicker installation

Tags: android, angular, mobile, nativescript

My Android NS app isn't running since I added the nativescript-plugin-filepicker plugin. **I see that with each build, the FragmentClass.java in platfroms is being recreated**. I tried cleaning, rerunning etc...

The error I get when running:

```
C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\App_Resources\\Android\\before-plugins.gradle
\+ applying user-defined configuration from C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\App_Resources\\Android\\before-plugins.gradle
\+ setting applicationId
\+ applying user-defined configuration from C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\App_Resources\\Android\\app.gradle
\+ adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules@nativescript\\core\\platforms\\android\\core.aar
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules@nativescript\\core\\platforms\\android\\widgets-release.aar
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules@nativescript\\google-signin\\platforms\\android\\googlesignin-release.aar  
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules\\nativescript-google-login\\platforms\\android\\nativescript_google_login.aar
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules\\nativescript-google-login\\platforms\\android\\nativescript_google_signin.aar
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules\\nativescript-ui-core\\platforms\\android\\TNSCore-release.aar
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules\\tns-core-modules-widgets\\platforms\\android\\widgets-release.aar
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules\\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\\platforms\\android\\TNSSideDrawer-release.aar  
\+ adding aar plugin dependency: C:\\Users...\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\node_modules\\nativescript-plugin-filepicker\\platforms\\android\\nativescript_plugin_filepicker.aar

Error executing Static Binding Generator: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior.
Please change the name of one of the extended classes.
File:C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\platforms\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\tns\\FragmentClass.java Class: com.tns.FragmentClass
Detailed log here: C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Clapp1.0.0\\platforms\\android\\build-tools\\runSbg.log

Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.
PS C:\\Users...\>
```

I tried adding

```
"nativescript": {
  "android": {
    "generationConfig": {
      "excludeClasses": [
        "com.tns.FragmentClass"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

to package.json, but then i get

```
Build file 'C:\Users\...\Documents\Clapp1.0.0\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 168
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Cannot get property 'android' on null object

Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.
```